# GTM - Trigg a floodlight pixel when someone has navigated to two random page URLs from landing page

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to implement a floodlight pixel that measures quality visitors on a website. In this case a quality visitor will be defined as a visitor that has visited two pages on the webpage like the flow below:

1. Entered the websites landing page (www.example.com)
2. Navigated to one page (www.example.com/page1)
3. Navigated to one more page (www.example.com/page2)

My ambition is to implement this through GTM. There's a lot of guides on how to trigg pixels with a certain amount of scrolling, time etc. but I can't find anything with above problem.

Do someone have any good ideas how to do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is:

Fire tag, when user visited any 3 pages per user session. Steps how to setup that in GTM:

**Create variable**

Go to Variables -> User Defined - Create

Type: JavaScript variable

Name: Visited Pages Per Session

Code:

```
function () {
    function createCookie(name,value) {
        document.cookie = name + "=" + value + "; path=/";
    }
    function readCookie(name) {
        var nameEQ = name + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
            if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
        }
        return 0;
    }
    var visits = parseInt(readCookie('visitedPagesPerSession')) || 0;
    visits++;
    createCookie('visitedPagesPerSession',visits)
    return visits;
}
```

**Create trigger**

This trigger should fire, when number of visited pages is 3

Go to Triggers -> New

Trigger Name: VisitedThreePagesTrigger

Type: Custom Event

EventName: VisitedThreePages

Fires on: Some Custom Events

Condition:

`Visited Pages Per Session` - `equals` - `3`

**Usage**

Then you can create any tag and assign this trigger `VisitedThreePagesTrigger`

Comment: Victor! Thank you very much. I will test this and get back to you :) Again, thank you very much. Exactly what I was looking for.